# mysql select query get data from row based

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 4 tables:

- source
- fields(fields for the source)
- source_data
- source_data_details(child of source_data, containing records saved in row technique)

[image]

```
source
id    name    status
1     web     active


field
id   source_id    name      config    status
1    1            record_id 101       active
2    1            firstname 101       active
3    1            surname   101       active

source_data
id   source_id    status
1    1            active
2    1            active

source_data_details
id    source_data_id    source_field_id    value
1     1                 1                  1avhh2
2     1                 2                  john
3     1                 3                  mavrick
4     2                 1                  87k3jo
5     2                 2                  peter
6     2                 3                  lyne
```

How can I query it to make the result

```
source_data.id           record_id    firstname    surname
1                        1avhh2       john         mavrick
2                        87k3jo       peter        lyne
```

Comment: This question looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple joins or aggregation.  Here is an example using aggregation:

```
select sdd.source_data_id, 
       max(case when f.name = 'record_id' then sdd.value end) as record_id,
       max(case when f.name = 'firstname' then sdd.value end) as firstname,
       max(case when f.name = 'surname' then sdd.value end) as surname
from source_data_details sdd join
     field f
     on sdd.field_id = f.id
group by sdd.source_data_id;
```

Note that you have to explicitly put in every column you want in the output.  If you want variable columns then you need to use dynamic SQL (`prepare`/`execute` statements).

Comment: I have to make it dynamic based on the field table.let us say that I am getting the data of a source with particular fields and getting the source_data_details for it\